# RadDesktopAlert Click Event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

Working with the RadDesktopAlert WinForms component by Telerik, I am wondering how can I perform an action when the user clicks anywhere on the alert window.

To put it blunt, the buttons suck, and it is much more natural (easier) for a user to just click anywhere in the window.  I checked the basics, and there doesn't appear to be an event for "Click", nor does it appear to expose it's Hwnd or Handle.

The events that are available are

- Closed
- Closing
- Disposed
- Disposing
- Opened
- Opening
- PropertyChanged
- RadPropertyChanged
- RadPropertyChanging

The problem with the buttons is the UI looks wacky when trying to right-align, and the "click" event doesn't fire unless you click well inside the button - TWICE.   So using the Buttons are not an option. What I am looking for is a place to write code that runs when the user clicks anywhere on the RadDesktopAlert box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RadDesktopAlert component, has a Popup property, which holds the actual popup element. You can use its Click event for the purpose:

```
AddHandler radDesktopAlert1.Popup.Click, AddressOf Popup_Click
```